# I don't understand this response?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, probability-theory, random-variables

Choose a circular disk of radius r on the cartesian plane. What's the probability it is not cut by horizontal lines with integer y intercept, or vertical lines with integer x intercept?

This was the response: 
For a fixed $r$, if $r>1/2$, the probability is 0 (the circle will certainly intersect one of the lines). Now, suppose you fixed $0<r<1$. Then, choosing the circle is equivalent to choosing its center. Consider every square in the plane with vertices $(n,m), (n+1,m), (n+1,m+1), (n, m+1), n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$. If you pick a point in a certain square, there is only a certain region inside which the circle will not cut the lines (which, in this case, are the borders of the square). It's easy to see that the allowable region in this case is a square of side $1-2r$. If you were to pick a point only inside the square, the probability would be the ratio of the areas of the squares: $(1-2r)^2$.

But you have to pick a point in the plane. The intuitive idea is that the ratio of the areas is preserved no matter how many squares you pick, and should be generalizable to the whole plane. The formal way to proceed, though, would probably to construct an equivalence relation between points, under which two points are equivalent iff they are corresponding points from different squares (i.e. the both are centers of some square). You would then have a new, special square, which behaves exactly as I said before (but is, actually, only the collection of all classes of equivalence). You can now proceed as before.

By this argument, the probability is $(1-2r)^2$.

I don't understand where the vertices come from and how this square applies. Also, what is this equivalence relation between points that he is talking about? I posted a comment on the original post, but he has not been responding.

Comment: I did but, no one was responding.

Comment: As for me it is fine to open a new question asking about an old one if there are no responses there, but at least then put a link to the old question, @CodingWolf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, they've restricted $r \leq 1/2.$  That wasn't in the original problem statement.

Let's say that the circle runs into one of the grid lines if its center ventures a distance $a$ from the center of the square in either the $x$ or the $y$ direction, in either the positive or negative direction.  Then, the condition of not running into the grid lines boils down to $r+a \leq 1/2$ in either the $x$ or the $y$ direction.

So, $a \leq \frac{1}{2} - r.$  This corresponds to a square area in the center with side $2a = 1 - 2r.$

If the probability of landing on each point in the grid is uniform, then we just need to take the ratio of the areas, which is $(1-2r)^2/1^2$, or $(1-2r)^2$.

The fact that the entire $x-y$ plane is under discussion goes away by symmetry.  Each square is as likely to get the circle as any other, and they're all the same.